# How to resolve Accelerated Mobile Pages Prohibited or invalid use of HTML Tag (Critical issue)?

Tags: amp-html

[image]

As per above image I want to remove all errors. I was trying my best but still this is what comes.

Comment: What pages is it coming from? Are you logging that? Do you have the code of those pages?

Comment: I have also this program and I talk with my developer and he is changed all image tag and I got result most of error are removed but we are still working on this so best way to talk with your developer